# Dynamic Entity Names in Entity Framework Core (.Net 6)

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I am trying to implement the following dynamic tableName using Dependency Injection, but I am getting the error

> The type arguments for method DbContext.Set(string) cannot be inferred from the usage

Does anyone have an answer or another suggestion to create dynamic entity names?

```
var tableName = "Table1";
Type returnType;
switch (tableName)
{
 case "Table1":
   returnType = typeof(Table1EntityType);
   break;
 case "Table2":
   returnType = typeof(Table2EntityType);
   break;
}
var query = _context.Set(returnType) -- error occurs here
```

Comment: Compare the `DbContext.Set` Method in [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set) and [EF6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set). EF6 has an overload with a `Type` argument, EF Core does not.

Comment: I am using the EF Core method

Comment: The names are already dynamic. `Set<>()` or `Set` provide access to the entities, they don't map them - unless the type is encountered for the first time. That happens *dynamically* based on the mapping information provided by conventions, attributes or explicit calls in `OnConfiguring`. If you want to use a different table name specify it with `ToTable()`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you want "dynamic" table names? You can already use [ToTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypebuilderextensions.totable?view=efcore-7.0) or `ToView` if you want to explicitly specify every table name. Or you can [create your own conventions.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/bulk-configuration)

Comment: You can even create and use [multiple models for the same DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/dynamic-model)

Comment: It has nothing to do with DI. Also, even if you retrieve the corresponding `DbSet<T>`, the result type (`object`, `IQueryable`, `IQueryable<object>`) won't be very useful w/o some third party library like DynamicLINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF-Core does not have a `Set` method with a `Type` argument. You must use a generic Set method: `_context.Set<Table1EntityType>()`:

The problem is that you will need different types for `query`. Therefore, you will need to do this in a generic method:

```cs
void ExecuteQuery<T>()
{
    DbSet<T> query = _context.Set<T>();
    //TODO: do things with query.
}
```

The selection then goes like this:

```cs
var tableName = "Table1";
switch (tableName)
{
    case "Table1":
        ExecuteQuery<Table1EntityType>();
        break;
    case "Table2":
        ExecuteQuery<Table2EntityType>();
        break;
}
```

A problem arises, if you want to access properties of these entities. Since the C# compiler has no clues of what properties `T` has, you must add a type constraint:

```cs
void ExecuteQuery<T>() where T : CommonBaseTypeAndOrInterfaces
{
    DbSet<T> query = _context.Set<T>();
    //TODO: do things with query.
}
```

Now, you can reference properties available in `CommonBaseTypeAndOrInterfaces`.

Comment: I wonder why such a thing is even needed? `ToTable` can be used to change how each type is mapped. It seems there's even a way [to use different models for the same DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/dynamic-model)

Comment: Actually this is a good alternative. Let me know if you like to retract the duplicate closure.

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis! This worked perfect. Ivan please retract the duplicate closure